# Make alarm trigger after 5 sec in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want an alarm to trigger after 5 sec in android, but it's not working. It is triggering after 1 min instead 5 sec. Why?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager powerManager=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock= powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"Power Manager");

    wakeLock.acquire();
    showNotification("Wake up. Alarm Triggered",context);
}
public void showNotification(String message ,Context context)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent=new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),5000,pendingIntent);

}
```

}

Comment: but not working,  it is trigger every after 1 min instead 5 sec why?? can anyone solve

Comment: Android limited the repeat time of alarm manager to minimum 1minute

Comment: @Sujith Niraikulathan - you are right.. :) its limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).

If you want to do some action while your app is running (which is what I suppose from an interval of 5 seconds), use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

In particular, `postDelayed` or `sendMessageDelayed` might be the right choice for your application (however, as you did not tell us about your primary objective, that's just guesswork).

Answer (score 1):

Praviin, if you want to trigger something after 5 sec, just use handler like below. You don't need to put alarmManager codes inside handler.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                //The code here will run after 5 sec, do what you want

                            }
                        }, 5*1000);
```